# Separating "if else" statements

Tags: java, if-statement

What I need is to know how to split these two **if else** sections up.

```
    public static int NextBday(int Bdays, int days){
int daysleft = 0;
     if (days > Bdays) {
        daysleft= (365+Bdays) - days;
    }else if(Bdays > days){
        daysleft= Bdays-days;            
    }if (Bdays == days + 1) {
        System.out.println("\nWow, your birthday is tomorrow!");
    }else if (Bdays == days){
        System.out.println("\nHappy birthday!");
    }
    System.out.println("\nYour birthday is in " +daysleft+ " days");
return daysleft;
```

If you can't tell from the mess what I want is to separate the if statements into two different parts but still leave it in the same method. What do I need to do to so that the second if else statement can print by itself without having to show how many days are left?

e.g. **"Wow, your birthday is tomorrow!"** without the **"Your birthday is in 1 days"**

and **"Happy Birthday"**
 without the "**Your birthday is in 0 days"**

Keeping it simple would help the most.  Does anyone need the full code? I can try to phrase the question differently if anyone's confused. Thank you very much to all who help!

Comment: You should do your printing logic in whatever calls NextBday()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public static int NextBday(int Bdays, int days){
int daysleft = 0;
     if (days > Bdays) {
        daysleft= (365+Bdays) - days;
    }else if(Bdays > days){
        daysleft= Bdays-days;            
    }

    if (Bdays == days + 1) {
        System.out.println("\nWow, your birthday is tomorrow!");
    }else if (Bdays == days){
        System.out.println("\nHappy birthday!");
    } else
       System.out.println("\nYour birthday is in " +daysleft+ " days");
return daysleft;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Bdays - days != 1 && Bdays != days){ //if it's not today or tomorrow
    int daysleft;
    System.out.println("\nYour birthday is in " + (daysleft = (int)((days > Bdays)?(365+Bdays-days):(Bdays-days))) + " days."); //print the message, and calculate the correct number of days on the spot
    return daysleft;
}
else{ //if it is today or tomorrow
    System.out.println(((Bdays == days)?"\nHappy Birthday!":"\nWow, your birthday is tomorrow!")); //If it's today, print happy birthday, if it's not today it must be tomorrow. 
    return Bdays - days;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the == cases first, and only check the other two cases if neither if the == cases are true.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to add return; statements in the last two if() cases:

```
    public static int NextBday(int Bdays, int days){
int daysleft = 0;
     if (days > Bdays) {
        daysleft= (365+Bdays) - days;
    }else if(Bdays > days){
        daysleft= Bdays-days;            
    }if (Bdays == days + 1) {
        System.out.println("\nWow, your birthday is tomorrow!");
        return daysleft;
    }else if (Bdays == days){
        System.out.println("\nHappy birthday!");
        return daysleft;
    }
    System.out.println("\nYour birthday is in " +daysleft+ " days");
return daysleft;
```

Paul Tomblin's answer is cleaner, though.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework so I'll be a little bit vague rather than just giving you the answer.

Try to think about your code in terms of how you would describe the function in English. Then turn that into pseudocode, then into real code.

"If it's someone's birthday today then say happy birthday. Or, if their birthday is tomorrow, say 'Wow'. Otherwise just say how many days remain until their birthday."

Psuedocode:

```
if birthdayToday
    print happy birthday message
otherwise if birthdayTomorrow
    print wow message
otherwise
    print days remaining message
```

The last step is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, because the most possible case is (> 1) so we put that option the first one.

```
int diff = Bdays - days;
if (diff > 1){
    System.out.println("\nYour birthday is in " +diff+ " days");
}
else if (diff == 1){
    System.out.println("\nWow, your birthday is tomorrow!");
}
else{
    System.out.println("\nHappy birthday!");
}
```

Comment: I think you need `if(diff < 0) diff += 365;` or similar.

Comment: Yes I am just focusing on the specified if part.

Comment: -1; re-ordering like this is a premature optimization. Rather, using "most possible" as justification for the ordering is misguided; the cases we handle first are the ones that (i) make the rest of the logic simpler, if it makes a difference; or (ii) failing that, are the more **interesting** ones - because those are the ones that should be brought to the code-reader's attention; special cases are special. Let the compiler worry about re-ordering (even if that compiler is `javac`).

Comment: What's premature about it? Your objections are absurd. The most likely case should certainly be evaluated first, especially if it is 363.2425 time as likely, as here. I fail to see how the compiler could deduce rhat particular piece of domain knowledge. The reordering doesn't detract from readability and they don't affect the other matters you refer to either. Upvoted your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static int NextBday(int Bdays, int days){
  int daysleft = getDaysLeft(Bdays,days);//move logic to a private function
  if (daysleft == 1)
   System.out.println("\nWow, your birthday is tomorrow!");
  else if (daysleft == 0)
   System.out.println("\nHappy birthday!");
  else        
   System.out.println("\nYour birthday is in " +daysleft+ " days");
  return daysleft;
 }

 private static int getDaysLeft(int Bdays, int days) {
  if (days > Bdays)
   return (365 + Bdays) - days;
  return Bdays - days; //no need to check for the < condition        
 }
```

**OR**

```
 public static int NextBday(int Bdays, int days) {
    int daysleft = days > Bdays ? 365 + Bdays - days : Bdays - days;
     if (daysleft == 1)
        System.out.println("\nWow, your birthday is tomorrow!");
     else if (daysleft == 0)
        System.out.println("\nHappy birthday!");
     else
        System.out.println("\nYour birthday is in " + daysleft + " days");

    return daysleft;
    }
```